# Error creating bean : NameController Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

the problem is that  @autowiring doesn't work , i followed all the search results but still getting this error "Error creating bean : NameController Injection of autowired dependencies failed;",any help would be much appreciated.

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'travailController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pcd.service.TravailService com.pcd.restcontroller.TravailController.travailServ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'travailServ': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.pcd.repository.TravailRepository com.pcd.serviceImpl.TravailServiceImpl.travailRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'travailRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property saveTravail found for type Travail!
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TravailController {

@Autowired  
TravailService travailServ; 
@Autowired
MatiereService matiereServ;     
@Autowired
GroupeService groupeServ;


@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("travail")Travail travail, 
  BindingResult result) {

  travailServ.saveTravail(new Travail());
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/travail");
 }


  @RequestMapping(value = { "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newGroupe(@ModelAttribute("travail") Travail travail,ModelMap model,BindingResult result ) {


        model.addAttribute("travail", travail);
        model.addAttribute("matieres", matiereServ.findAlmatieres());

        model.addAttribute("groupes", groupeServ.findAllGroupes());
        model.addAttribute("listTravail", travailServ.findAllTravail());

        return "travail";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.travailServ.deleteTravailById(id);
        return "redirect:/travail";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("travail", travailServ.findById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listTravail", travailServ.findAllTravail());
        return "travail";
    }
```

TravailServiceImpl:

```
@Service("travailServ")

public class TravailServiceImpl implements TravailService{

@Autowired
 private TravailRepository travailRepository;
@Override
public List<Travail> findAllTravail() {
    try{
        return (List<Travail>) travailRepository.findAll();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
@Override

public Travail findById(int id) {
    return travailRepository.findById(id);
}
@Override

public Travail findByTitre(String titre) {

      return travailRepository.findByTitre(titre);
}
@Override
@Transactional
public Travail findByDescription(String description) {
      return travailRepository.findByDescription(description);
}
@Override
public void deleteTravailById(int id) {
      travailRepository.delete(id);

}
@Override
public void saveTravail(Travail travail) {
    travailRepository.save(travail);

}
```

TravailService:

```
public interface TravailService {

 List<Travail> findAllTravail();

 Travail findById(int id);

 Travail findByTitre(String titre);

 Travail findByDescription(String description);
 void saveTravail(Travail travail);

 void deleteTravailById(int id);


}
```

TravailRepository:

```
public interface TravailRepository extends CrudRepository<Travail, Integer> {
 List<Travail> findAllTravail();

 Travail findById(int id);
 Travail findByTitre(String titre);
 Travail findByDescription(String description);
 void saveTravail(Travail travail);

 void deleteTravailById(int id);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `TravailRepository` interface methods for which **Spring container is going to provide the implementation at runtime** during startup.

Basically, **Spring data JPA has got few rules to implement (during container startup) the methods in the Repository interface** and it is failing because of your method names `saveTravail` and `deleteTravailById`.

So, remove the following methods from your `TravailRepository` interface:

```
 void saveTravail(Travail travail);

 void deleteTravailById(int id);
```

Rather, you can directly use those methods (i.e., `save(S entity)` and `delete(ID id)`) from `CrudRepository` (look API [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.9.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html))